Sorting by any Value.Field in ConcurrentDictionary
I'm trying to load a GridView with a ConcurrentDictionary<string, object> (as List()) and allow any field (key or object.field) to be sortable. To wit:
public static ConcurrentDictionary<string, Detail> myDic = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Detail>();

public class Detail
{
    public int val1;
    public bool val2;
    public DateTime val3;
    public long val4;
}

// myDic is loaded elsewhere and does have correct data

private void LoadGridView(string sortBy = "Key")
{
    Type valType = typeof(Detail);
    PropertyInfo pInfo;

    // method #1:
    pInfo = valType.GetProperty(sortBy);        // <-- always returns null

    // method #2:
    FieldInfo fInfo = valType.GetField(sortBy);             // <-- always returns correct field info
    pInfo = fInfo.ReflectedType.GetProperty(fInfo.Name);    // <-- always returns null

    // fails when sortBy != "Key"
    GridView1.DataSource = myDic.OrderBy(x => sortBy == "Key" 
        ? x.Key 
        : pInfo.GetValue(x.Value)
    ).ToList();

    GridView1.DataBind();
}

Obviously, I'm doing either Method #1 or #2 when testing - not both!  ;)
When I specify sortBy = a Detail field ("val1", "val2", etc. - spelling, capitalization verified) pInfo is always null and the assignment to the DataSource fails.
Thanks in advance for your help!

Well, you don't have any properties (nothing that defines accessors like get and set) so that's why the method GetProperty is returning null. You do have fields, which is why GetField is returning something.  I think you want fInfo.GetValue(x.Value)

you can try sorted dictionary https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.sorteddictionary-2?view=net-8.0&redirectedfrom=MSDN

@HereticMonkey: Oh sheesh! You know when you look at code too long ... and you're dehydrated and lacking sleep .... I'm going to go fix that right now. Thanks!

you did not provided any data. so i had to create my own....
change parameter to Key, val1 or val4 to see orderby
void Main()
{
    Enumerable.Range(1, 100).ToList().AsParallel().ForAll(fe=> {
        myDic.AddOrUpdate("A"+fe, new Detail() { val1 = fe, val2 = true, val3 = DateTime.Now, val4 = GetLong() }, (_, old) => old); 
    });
        
    string sortBy = "val4";
    LoadGridView(sortBy);
}

public long GetLong()
{
    var r = new Random();
    return r.Next(0, 1000) * 2;
}

private void LoadGridView(string sortBy)
{
        myDic
        .OrderBy(p => sortBy != "Key" ? p.Value.GetType().GetField(sortBy).GetValue(p.Value) : p.Key) 
        .ToList()
        .Dump();
}

public ConcurrentDictionary<string, Detail> myDic = new  ConcurrentDictionary<string, Detail>();

public class Detail
{
    public int val1;
    public bool val2;
    public DateTime val3;
    public long val4;
    public Detail(){}
}

